# Slider Filter for Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a case where a product has two attributes:

- Attribute 1: 10
- Attribute 2: 20-100

---

I need to create a filter or to add a plugin that will enable me the following functionality:

Three slider filters:

- One to determine a range for Attribute 1
- Second to determine a range for min value of Attribute 2
- Third to determine a range for max value of Attribute 2

---

For example:

- I choose 5-15 in the first slider
- 20-40 in the second slider
- 80-120 in the third slider

and it will show only the products that have all three and including the product I previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You look: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/. It seems interesting and has slider function.